# How do I add onsubmit or onclick validation logic to my Lift form using CSS binding?

Tags: scala, lift

I have a form working with CSS selector binding and Scala-side validation. Now I want to add javascript validation either via my own jQuery code that I call or else the built-in commands like JsIf.

Here is my current code:

```
def create = {
    "#description" #> SHtml.textarea(maintRV.is.description.get,
        name => maintRV.is.description(name) ) &
    "#submit" #> SHtml.onSubmitUnit(processSubmit)
}
```

How can I add onclick or onsubmit behavior to the SHtml.onSubmitUnit binding? I have already used Ajax forms in other parts of my code, but for this page that seems like overkill. I don't mind a regular form submit. I just want to add client-side validation.

I've combed SimplyLift, Exploring Lift and the groups and can't find it.

Comment: Are you just looking to add the attribute to the form (or other tags), like: `"form [onclick]" #> "jsFunction();"` or are you looking to have the javascript called as part of the `onSubmit` function?

Comment: @jcern, adding an attribute would be fine. The best would be `"form [onsubmit]" #> "jsFunction();"`. Is that possible? I just want the javascript validation logic I've already written outside of Scala to be called onsubmit so that the submit doesn't even go to Lift if the field validation fails.

Comment: I believe you can do that with a normal form. However, if you are using an ajax form, then Lift adds its own onSubmit to the form. In that case though, you could use an ajax submit button action that executes a `JsCmd` and you'd be able to execute it there.

Comment: I'm using a normal form, but it didn't work. Looks like I'll just have to make all my forms ajax forms and handle it that way.

Comment: Ajax should work, but two small things to point out. First, I noticed you didn't have a return before the jsFunction - to prevent submission you'd probably need: `[onsubmit] #> "return jsFunction()"`. The other thing is, you could probably use jQuery on page load to bind the function to the form's submission.

Comment: Well, I put a return in when I tried it, but no markup was inserted into the source. Even with the CSS transform in place it didn't add any onsubmit listener. I just ended up putting jQuery on the page and forgoing trying to do it from the Scala snippet.